# (Codelgniter) Login page is not redirecting to source page in godaddy hosting server

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I have used codeigniter to develop project.In Localhost it is working fine(Redirecting Also)But after hosting in godaddy Server if I login with correct details it is showing error.But in url it is showing domainame/controller.finally same login page is showing.

I Changed  settings also according to server.

it is not Connecting to database even if i change database.php(host,username,password,database name)....and iam unable to getting users details from database

Comment: can you add error message in your question?

Comment: Please add you error message, Also make sure that you are able to connect DB for getting user details for authentication.

Comment: This can be down to a number of things. Could you provide your .htaccess, application/config/config.php file (obviously remove an sensitive data) and your routes file? First check would be to see if the page works if you add index.php into the url.

Comment: Actually The problem is Not Connecting to database even if changed database.php settings(host,username,password,database name)...

Comment: Solved,the one and only Solution is we have to give Server IP Address inside database.